# Package acceptance validation error: The package Documents.msix doesn't contain any Application elements in the app manifest file

Tags: xml, manifest, msix

I made a .exe from a .py and from there I made an installator and then  passed it to msix with the windows tool.

when uploading the .msix, this error appears:

Package acceptance validation error: The package Documents.msix doesn't contain any Application elements in the app manifest file.

how can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to package a Python project into MSIX package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074128/how-to-package-a-python-project-into-msix-package)

Comment: It seems like you incorrectly configured your MSIX package, check out the SO question linked above, it has more details on how to create an MSIX package for a python app

Comment: man! this is great! didnt see this before .. thanks you both!

Comment: solution:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yf-eDsRrnM